# how to keep div closed to another div

Tags: wordpress

I have to be centered a div, till here all is clear, but, I need to keep closed at left another div.

No boht centered, just center one div and keep sticky another one.

In my example, the center div (menu) and sticky div (logo.)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe that's what you mean?
https://jsfiddle.net/g8c8wp34/1/

HTML:

```
<div class="layout-wrapper">
    <div class="logo">
        Logo
    </div>
    <div class="menu">
        <a href="#">item 1</a>
        <a href="#">item 2</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="layout-wrapper">
    <div class="col col1"></div>
    <div class="col col2"></div>
    <div class="col col3"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.layout-wrapper {
  width: 400px;
  background: #ccc;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.logo {
  position: absolute;
  background: #ddd;
  width: 60px;
  margin-left: -60px;
}
.col {
  width: 32%;
  background: #cdcdcd;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  height: 30px;
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.col1 {
  margin-right:2%
}
.col3 {
  margin-left:2%
}
```

Or this (with fixed position logo): https://jsfiddle.net/g8c8wp34/2/

Comment: I think first solution is exactly I need, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

So, you want the menu to be centered and sticked to it's left a logo?

```
<div class="centered">
 <div id="logo"></div>
 <div id="menu"></div>
</div>
```

Wrap them into a div an center it. Float left the logo and right the menu.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/fk3ykqy0/1/) you have the jsfiddle.

Tell me if this helps you!

Comment: Hi Javier, I think you don't understand my problem. In your example the blue one must be centered and the black one close them.